# Closure arguments: passing a function that mutates the inner variables

Tags: rust, closures, state

The idea is to to have one closure (`change_x` in this case) that captures state (`x` in this case) that takes a function as its parameter(`alterer`) that would dictate *how* the inner state changes.

```rust
pub fn plus17(h: & u64) -> u64 {
    *h + 17
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = 0; //take x by reference

    let mut change_x = move |alterer: &dyn FnOnce(&u64) ->u64 |  alterer(&x) ;
    change_x(&mut plus17);

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

I can't seem to get the types right however:

```rust
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r u64) -> u64: the size of dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r u64) -> u64 cannot be statically determined
  --> playground/src/main.rs:19:69
   |
19 |     let mut increment_x = move |alterer: &dyn FnOnce(&u64) ->u64 |  alterer(&x) ;
   |                                                                     ^^^^^^^

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*alterer` which is behind a shared reference
  --> playground/src/main.rs:19:69
   |
19 |     let mut increment_x = move |alterer: &dyn FnOnce(&u64) ->u64 |  alterer(&x) ;
   |                                                                     ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*alterer` has type `dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r u64) -> u64`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm not sure if i'm justified in putting the `dyn` where i put it, it was a compiler's suggestion and im not really sure why i have to put it there. Is it because the `alterer` can be of arbitrary size despite the input/return type of `&u64->u64`?

I have also tried to make alterer a `FnMut` as opposed to `FnOnce`, but im also pretty shaky as to their distinction and the fact that a given `alterer` would run only once (at the moment of invocation by outer closure `change_x`) seemed reasonable.

Comment: Please always post the **full** error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FnOnce` needs an owned `self`. Thus `alterer` cannot be `FnOnce`, because it is not owned but a reference.

You can either make it `&dyn Fn` or `&mut dyn FnMut` (I'd recommend going with `FnMut`), or take `Box<dyn FnOnce>`.

Comment: Worked as a cham. Thanks! 
Why exactly does `FnOnce` require a `self`:what is the `self`'s connection with the ownership/reference? And how does making a `FnMut` solve that? 

The `FnMut` doc says this, but it is very opaque to me: _Since `FnOnce` is a supertrait of `FnMut`, any instance of `FnMut` can be used where a `FnOnce` is expected, and since `Fn` is a subtrait of `FnMut`, any instance of `Fn` can be used where `FnMut` is expected_

Comment: @rtviii There are three traits, `FnOnce`, `FnMut` and `Fn`, taking `self`, `&mut self` and `&self` respectively. `self` is just `self: Self`, i.e. move `self`. `&mut self` is `self: &mut Self`, so only requires borrowing `self`.